# memcache.get returns wrong object (Celery, Django)

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, celery

Here is what we have currently:

1. we're trying to get cached django model instance, cache key includes name of model and instance id. Django's standard memcached backend is used. This procedure is a part of common procedure used very widely, not only in celery.
2. sometimes(randomly and/or very rarely) cache.get(key) returns wrong object: either int or different model instance, even same-model-different-id case appeared. We catch this by checking correspondence of model name & id and cache key.
3. bug appears only in context of three of our celery tasks, never reproduces in python shell or other celery tasks. *UPD: appears under long-running CPU-RAM intensive tasks only*
4. cache stores correct value (we checked that manually at the moment the bug just appeared)
5. calling same task again with same arguments might don't reproduce the issue, although probability is much higher, so bug appearances tend to "group" in same period of time
6. restarting celery solves the issue for the random period of time (minutes - weeks)
7. *NEW* this isn't connected with memory overflow. We always have at least 2Gb free RAM when this happens.
8. *NEW* we have `cache_instance = cache.get_cache("cache_entry")` in static code. During investigation, I found that at the moment the bug happens `cache_instance.get(key)` returns wrong value, although `get_cache("cache_entry").get(key)` on the next line returns correct one. This means either bug disappears too quickly or for some reason cache_instance object got corrupted.
   Isn't cache instance object returned by django's cache thread safe?
9. *NEW* we logged very strange case: as another wrong object from cache, we got model instance w/o id set. This means, the instance was never saved to DB therefore couldn't be cached. (I hope)
10. *NEW* At least one `MemoryError` was logged these days

I know, all of this sounds like some sort of magic.. And really, any ideas how that's possible or how to debug this would be very appreciated.

PS: My current assumption is that this is connected with multiprocessing: as soon as cache instance is created in static code and before Worker process fork this would lead to all workers sharing same socket (Does it sound plausibly?)

Comment: Found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/x1ZnV7rj8Tk
Seems to be connected, but that bug was reported and is marked as fixed.

Comment: try running your memcache in more verbose (-vv) and filter down based on your key, you might be able to better explain where exactly it's going wrong

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried on different hardware?

Comment: Is your memcached actually a cluster and which memcached client are you using in Django?  I suspect that at times of high usage one of your nodes is responding too slowly so it's flagged as DOWN.  When we used memcached with celery we also fronted smaller clusters of memcached with Moxi to handle the failover.

Comment: @frederick_c_siu our memcached is a cluster, but as far as I understand memcached client returns None in case corresponding node is flagged.

Comment: @Knyght I'm pretty sure issue isn't related with hardware because it's virtual machine in Amazon EC2 cluster. Also we have actually multiple machines with same software configuration and all of them are vulnerable for this bug.

Comment: is it possible the value of key isn't what you think it is? perhaps some kind of thread safety issue.

Comment: @Charles, nope, logging showed correct key passed to memcached client

Comment: @muzhig still think it's some kind of thread safety issue, which makes sense if you suspect multiprocessing is the culprit. Hard to debug these things without code, if possible try building it down to a repeatable example and posting it here.

Comment: I recently had a somewhat similar issue that was solved by placing KEY_PREFIX in the CACHE settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been bugging me for a while until I found this question and answer. I just want to add some things I've learnt.

You can easily reproduce this problem with a local memcached instance:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
import os

def write_read_test():
    pid = os.getpid()
    cache.set(pid, pid)
    for x in range(5):
        value = cache.get(pid)
        if value != pid:
            print "Unexpected response {} in process {}. Attempt {}/5".format(
                    value, pid, x+1)
    os._exit(0)

cache.set("access cache", "before fork")
for x in range(5):
    if os.fork() == 0:
        write_read_test()
```

What you can do is close the cache client as Django does in the `request_finished` signal:

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/**init**.py#L128](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/__init__.py#L128)

If you put a `cache.close()` after the fork, everything works as expected.

For celery you could [connect to a signal that is fired after the worker is forked](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-ready) and execute `cache.close()`.

This also affects gunicorn when preload is active and the cache is initialized before forking the workers.

For gunicorn, you could [use `post_fork` in your gunicorn configuration](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#post-fork):

```
def post_fork(server, worker):
    from django.core.cache import cache
    cache.close()
```

Comment: In the context of Django 1.11, Celery 4.1 and a pool of 8 workers, I found out the proper signal to connect to is `worker_process_init` (http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init) 

`worker_ready` was firing only once at boot and never again when the workers were cycled upon reaching the configured `worker_max_tasks_per_child`

Comment: Also, if using multiple cache backends, it's better off to call: `from django.core import cache; cache.close_caches()`

django.core.cache.cache is a proxy to the default cache backend. This may not fit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it finally:

1. Celery has dynamic scaling feature- it's capable to add/kill workers according to load
2. It does it via forking existing one
3. Opened sockets and files are copied to the forked process, so both processes share them, which leads to race condition, when one process reads response of another one. Simply, it's possible that one process reads response intended for second one, and vise-versa.
4. `from django.core.cache import cache` this object stores pre-connected memcached socket. Don't use it when your process could be dynamically forked.. and don't use stored connections, pools and other.
5. OR store them under current PID, and check it each time you're accessing cache

Comment: @mrcrgl I was almost sure I'm the only lucky one who faced this issue :)